# recover user if user gets delete by mistake

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I used command "userdel "  for delete user but that user environmental file has not deleted then how can I get back that user

Comment: Which "environmental file" ?

Comment: Why are you expecting the user's environment and/or home directory to be removed by userdel?

Comment: Perhaps research whether you can, and how to, create a new user and set that new user's home directory to an existing directory? I don't know if that is possible, and I'm only guessing that is what you're trying to do.